# How to extend class and maintain references?

Tags: swift, interface-builder, extension-methods

I have a UIPickerView in my ViewController class.  I also have an IBOutlet for the UIPickerView.  I've created an extension and put all of the UIPickerView code in it.  It is still in the ViewController file.  That builds and runs fine.

Now I want to move all of this extension code into its own Swift file.  When I do that, references to the UIPickerView IBOutlet throw errors. How do I fix this?